# Зацикливание при добавлении элемента в хеш-таблицу с открытой адресацией

Tags: c++, оптимизация, хеширование

Имеется хеш-таблица с открытой адресацией разрешающая коллизии двойным хешированием. Реализованы функции вычисления хешей `myHash(key)`, `myHash2(key)`, перехеширование `rehash()` при достижении определённого коэффициента заполнения `alpha`, удаление ключа. Идёт проблема с добавлением ключа

```
bool CHashTable::Add( const string& key)
{
    if(keysCount >= alpha*table.size()) {
        rehash();
    }
    const int hash1 = myHash(key);
    const int hash2 = myHash2(key);
    int hash = hash1;
    for(;(table[hash]!=N)&&(table[hash]!=key);hash = (hash+hash2)%table.size()){};
    if(table[hash] == key) {
        return false;
    }
    hash = hash1;
    for(;(table[hash]!=N)&&(table[hash]!=D);hash = (hash+hash2)%table.size()){};
    table[hash] = key;
    ++keysCount;
    return true;
}
```

Проблема в том, что зацикливание происходит, когда каждая из ячеек содержит либо какой-то ключ, не совпадающий с введённым, либо D - удалённый ключ. Как наиболее эффективно решить эту проблему? Если я верно понимаю, то нужно сделать две дополнительные переменные: первая хранит индекс начала проверки ячейки, а вторая содержит переменную типа bool, которая изменяется при повторном проходе через индекс начала проверки. Что ещё здесь можно улучшить для ускорения работы?

Comment: Что означает данное выражение table[hash]!=N

Comment: По умолчанию table пуст. Каждая ячейка заполнена string, значение которого описано в N. Данное выражение обозначает: пока не встретим пустую ячейку.

Comment: А почему у вас в двух циклах условия различаются? И зачем вообще два цикла вместо одного?

Comment: Первый цикл нужен для того, чтобы найти ключ или его свободную ячейку, помеченную N.
Второй цикл нужен для того, чтобы вставить ключ в ближайшее по числу проходов ячейку с элементом D.
Проблема в первом цикле, он не останавливается. Второй же цикл можно убрать, если же сделать хитрое условие в первом.

Comment: Думаю, тут проблема с величиной hash2. Величина hash2  должна быть взаимно простым числом с size. / Самым простым решением будет всегда делать простым size (вычисляете ближайшее большее от задаваемого/вычисляемого сейчас).

Comment: С величиной hash2 проблем нет. table.size() - степень 2, а hash2 равно (2*hash1+1)%table.size() - нечётное. hash1 вычисляется по методу Горнера, с параметром 91.

Comment: Ага. Просто недочитал текст вопроса до конца, а Вы не указали мой @ nick в своем комментарии, соответственно я его и не увидел. Вообще-то самый простой способ (код будет самым простым) это  никогда не заполнять таблицу до конца, всегда оставлять один элемент с значением `N`.

Comment: @avp То бишь перехеширование выполнять в двух случаях, когда достигается определённый коэффициент и когда не остаётся N?

Comment: Да, я вообще думаю, что rehash надо делать по `N`, а не keysCount (количество ключей в table?)

Comment: @avp, вы верно поняли, что `keysCount` - количество хранящихся ключей. Но делать это завязанным чисто на N - немного нерациональный подход, по-моему. Здесь присутствует моя недоговорка, есть операция удаления ключа из таблицы. Обозначим Add() - A, Remove() - R, тогда при последовательности операций АRARA....(тут разные ключи) размер хеш-таблицы будет увеличиваться, хотя хранится всего лишь один ключ. А как вы считаете?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26298/c-c

Comment: Это я долго комментарий, что нас попросили перейти в чат (и продолжать там, а я не хочу плодить новые чаты), набивал... Если не удастся, то отбейте комментарий тут и спросите на Мете почему у Вас зачатиться не выходит.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31424/discussion-between---and-avp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Довольно большое количество времени понадобилось, но работающая реализация выглядит так. Была попытка сделать это через while, но там не особо хорошее условие выходит, не говоря уже о том, что не правильно работает сама функция.

```
bool CHashTable::Add(const string& key)
{
if(keysCount>=alpha*table.size()){
    rehash();
}
const int hash1 = myHash(key);
const int hash2 = myHash2(key);
bool isFirstDeleted = true;
int firstDeleted = hash1;
int hash = hash1;
const int size = table.size();
for(int iterations = 0;iterations<size;++iterations){
    if(((table[hash]==D)||(table[hash]==N))&&isFirstDeleted){
        firstDeleted = hash;
        isFirstDeleted = false;
    }
    if(table[hash]==key){
        return false;
    }
    if(table[hash]==N){
        break;
    }
    hash = (hash+hash2)%table.size();
}
table[firstDeleted] = key;
++keysCount;
return true;
}
```